# What the heck is this invisible question and and answer post?

Tags: support, bug

I honestly don’t know [how I got to this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1510536) to even link to it, but what the heck is this about? I also cross-posted this on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340496/243319) because of the sheer oddness of it all and it seems far beyond a basic issue.

> [image: The thread that doesn’t exist.]

Comment: You clicked on the answers.  The question has not subject or title. I suspect that happens by modifying it within the grace period.

Comment: The author might have found a way to force the submit.

Comment: I think I actually caught the question on the main site with a title like "blank blank" or similar. The title disappeared right after I entered the post.

Comment: My impression was the question had been edited and the author is just trolling.

Comment: Negative. I have not.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The only way to view the question is by clicking on the "answers".